# awk/sed/grep to delete lines matching fields in another file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file1, that has a few lines (tens), and a much longer file2 (~500,000 lines). The lines in each file are not identical, although there is a subset of fields that are identical. I want to take fields 3-5 from each line in file1, and search file2 for the same pattern (just those three fields, in same order -- in file2, they fall in fields 2-4). If any match is found, then I want to delete the corresponding line from file1.

Eg, file1:

```
2016-01-06T05:38:31 2016-01-06T05:23:33 2016006 120E A TM Current
2016-01-06T07:34:01 2016-01-06T07:01:51 2016006 090E B TM Current
2016-01-06T07:40:44 2016-01-06T07:40:41 2016006 080E A TM Alt
2016-01-06T07:53:50 2016-01-06T07:52:14 2016006 090E A TM Current
2016-01-06T08:14:45 2016-01-06T08:06:33 2016006 080E C TM Current
```

file2:

```
2016-01-06T07:35:06.87 2016003 100E C NN Current 0
2016-01-06T07:35:09.97 2016003 100E B TM Current 6303
2016-01-06T07:36:23.12 2016004 030N C TM Current 0
2016-01-06T07:37:57.36 2016006 090E A TM Current 399
2016-01-06T07:40:29.61 2016006 010N C TM Current 0
```

... (and on for 500,000 lines)

So in this case, I want to delete the fourth line of file1 (in place).

The following finds the lines I want to delete:

```
grep "$(awk '{print $3,$4,$5}' file1)" file2
```

So one solution may be to pipe this to sed, but I'm unclear how to set a match pattern in sed from a piped input. And searching online suggests awk can probably do all of this (or perhaps sed, or something else), so wondering what a clean solution would look like.

Also, speed is somewhat important because other processes may attempt to modify the files while this is going on (I know this may present more complications...). Matches will generally be found at the end of file2, not the beginning (in case there is some way to search file2 from the bottom up).

Comment: pluse-uno for excellently described problem. Keep posting and Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{file2[$2,$3,$4]; next} !(($3,$4,$5) in file2)' file2 file1
2016-01-06T05:38:31 2016-01-06T05:23:33 2016006 120E A TM Current
2016-01-06T07:34:01 2016-01-06T07:01:51 2016006 090E B TM Current
2016-01-06T07:40:44 2016-01-06T07:40:41 2016006 080E A TM Alt
2016-01-06T08:14:45 2016-01-06T08:06:33 2016006 080E C TM Current
```

The fact that file2 contains 500,000 lines should be no problem for awk wrt memory or execution speed - it should complete in about 1 second or less even in the worst case.

With any UNIX command, to overwrite the original file you just do:

```
cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

so in this case:

```
awk '...' file2 file1 > tmp && mv tmp file1
```

Comment: Thanks. I see how this works, and it is pretty quick. I was trying to do it the other way around, reading file1 into an array (since its so much smaller), but I'm not clear how to then print lines from file1, that don't match.

Comment: So now you know that reading file1 into an array is the wrong approach, right? Doing that would save you memory but then you'd need to loop through the whole file1 array once for every line of file 2 so it would increase the amount of time the script would take to run by a multiplication factor of the number of lines in file1.

Comment: Eg, something like this: awk 'NR==FNR{file1[$3,$4,$5]; next} !(($2,$3,$4) in file1) {print XX }' file1 file2.   What could XX be? If we could simply grep file1 for ($2,$3,$4)  (now that we know it doesnt exist in file2), and print that, that would do the trick.

Comment: Forget awk for a moment and just write out the logic in plain language and you'll see why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, right, I see your point.  Can I easily limit the lines added to the file2 array, to those matching a condition (such as starting with a piece of a datestring, '2016-01-06' ). That would greatly reduce the size of file2 array.  I thought editing the start condition to: 'NR==FNR && /2016-01/ {...' might work, but no dice.

Comment: Yes but why are you trying to optimize a script that runs in 1 second? Instead of `NR==FNR && /2016-01/ {` you'd need `NR==FNR { if (/2016-01/) {` but it seems to be not worthwhile at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can find non-matching lines in `file1`:

```
$ grep -v -F -f <(awk '{ print $3,$4,$5 }' file2) file1
2016-01-06T05:38:31 2016-01-06T05:23:33 2016006 120E A TM Current
2016-01-06T07:34:01 2016-01-06T07:01:51 2016006 090E B TM Current
2016-01-06T07:40:44 2016-01-06T07:40:41 2016006 080E A TM Alt
2016-01-06T08:14:45 2016-01-06T08:06:33 2016006 080E C TM Current
```

Just redirect this somewhere and overwrite `file1` afterwards.

Comment: Absolutely do NOT do that as, even though it may produce the expected output given this sample input, in general you'll get false matches depending on the contents of the two files since it's greping for the file2 contents across the whole of every line of file1 instead of in just the target fields of file1.